# Bug that turns comments the same colour as strings?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I'm not sure if something is just wrong on my end, but I've found a couple of questions on SO over the last couple of weeks where the formatting of code appears to be wrong.

When someone uses ' to mark a comment (vb.net), the code that follows seems to go the same red colour that strings are, rather than the grey faded colour that they used to go?

Again, not sure if it's a problem my end or with SO, but this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39576389/6530111)
appears to behave this way. (Screenshot just to show that for me, this problem exists, at least)

[image]

Comment: `'`: Start of string. `'` in VB _that_ or Comment. How to distinguish between them?

Comment: See this post: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108)

Comment: @Tushar Are they not both apostrophes?

Comment: The [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39576389/revisions) shows the line that specifies that the code is VB getting edited out at one point. Looks like the OP fixed it.

Comment: @BSMP: ... why the heck was it edited out?

Comment: @BoltClock - I assumed it was an accident. My phone will decide to select and delete a whole chunk of text when I'm only trying to delete one character in certain apps, maybe something similar happened here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` hint is required in order for many VB.NET code blocks to be highlighted correctly, as they tend to be misidentified as the default language (which itself is not VB).

The hint was added in by one editor, and later... removed. I don't know why. But the post owner has since fixed it on their own. (Wow, you don't often see new (< 60 days) users knowing their way around the Stack Overflow revision system, and Stack Overflow Markdown. I gotta say I'm impressed.)